# Why I cannot see "Create an outgoing webhook" link?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I follow the instruction on this page. [Outgoing webhooks in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/outgoingwebhook)
but I cannot see the link "Create an outgoing webhook". What should I do?

Comment: Could you please ask your O365 tenant admin to [Allow sideloading of external apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant#turn-on-microsoft-teams-for-your-organization)(Step #5)? Please let us know if you see the option after enabling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could check 3 points:

1. You should be in a "Member" role or an "Owner" role. The link does not show if you are a "Guest" in the team.
2. If you are already a "Member", ask your team Owner to check if the permission is on. [Assign roles and permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-roles-permissions)
3. As [Wajeed - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8632976/wajeed-msft) mentioned, [Allow sideloading of external apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant#turn-on-microsoft-teams-for-your-organization) (Step #5)